# Getting 10 Year Average of Field Values using Rblpapi in R

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

I am trying to use `Rblpapi` to return a interval average of a field, for example a 10 year average of the `PE_RATIO` of `SPX`.

I'm stuck at

```
library(Rblpapi)
blpConnect(<connection details went here>)
bdp(c('SPX'), c('PE_RATIO'))
```

How can this be done? I am very new to `Rblpapi` and the Bloomberg API. Thank you!

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example to make it more clear as to what you're asking?

Comment: @Hack-R I am pretty new to `Rblpapi` and Bloomberg. `bdp(c('SPX'), c('PE_RATIO'))` gives me the current `PE_RATIO` (I think), but I will want the yearly `PE_RATIO` that is averaged over the past 10 years. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yea, I think I understand.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for can be easily achieved using the Bloomberg interval fields. These allow you to do analysis on historical series without having to retrieve the series itself. For example in your case of 10 year average PE for SPX you can do the following...

```
blpConnect()
ovrd <- c("CALC_INTERVAL"="10Y", "MARKET_DATA_OVERRIDE"="PE_RATIO")
bdp("SPX Index", "INTERVAL_AVG", overrides=ovrd)
```

Answer (score 0):

For historical data, you need to use bdh, not bdp. There are examples in the manual. In your case, it would look like:

```
bdh("SPX Index", c("PE_RATIO"))
```